# passing value to parent page from pop up using window.opener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a php value to the parent page from a pop up but all that happens is the pop up goes blank.  I am sure it is my syntax that is wrong.

```
die( '<script>window.opener.location.search=?week_start='.$week_start.'; window.close();</script>');
```

I would be grateful is someone could help me correct it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your corrected syntax:

```
die( '<script>window.opener.location.search=\'?week_start='.$week_start.'\'; window.close();</script>');
```